# How do I create an Azure Pipeline in Yaml to compile a python code using PyInstaller?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-yaml

**The Current Development Environment**

I have a working app in python created on MacOS using PyCharm.

**The Problem:**

I have 1 python file (main.py) that I wish to convert to a windows app using PyInstaller.

To do so, the command required is:

```
%> pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

I have managed to push my code (main.py) to Azure Repos (in azure DevOps). I want to now create a pipeline so that:

1. It launches a windows agent and runs the pyinstaller command on my code.
2. It produces an output file main.ext
3. I send that main.exe file to a directory on my oneDrive account

How would I go about creating the YAML file for this?

**So far working:**

I can obviously do a `git push` to push my code to Azure Repos. That's about it. I have no idea on how to execute a pipeline in YAML for this sort of scenario.

Comment: you could have a lok at the documentation to get started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops